# Django AttributeError Modifying Field Without Tracking Change History

Tags: django, model, field, admin, attributeerror

I am currently running a production Django webapp that holds historic item information using the SimpleHistory feature.

I have a navigation bar that displays all current revisions of all items to click on and view their separate pages. That being said, I wanted to have the ability to select which items to show/hide in the navigation bar by updating a boolean field on the item admin pages.

So, I modified the item models to have a field to do such:

```
class Item(models.Model)
field1 = models.CharField()
field2 = models.CharField()
...

hide_item = models.BooleanField('Item hidden:', default=True) #don't want history on this field

reason_for_change = models.CharField()
changed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
accepted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
accepted_date = models.DateTimeField()

history = HistoricalRecords()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

@property
def _history_user(self):
    return self.changed_by

@_history_user.setter
    self.changed_by = value
```

After making the migrations, this field showed up in the admin pages to my delight, but unfortunately I am not able to modify this field without receiving the following error:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simple_history\admin.py in save_model, line 151
151.         obj._history_user = request.user
```

I think it might have to do with the fact that all changes to item field need to be tracked using the SimpleHistory feature, but for this particular field I don't want to track and store the history of its changes, I just want to be able to enable and disable at will in the admin page.

I also noticed, that if I make a new instance of an Item on the webapp and check the value of hide_item on the admin item page, it is False when it should be True by default. On the contrary, if I attempt to add a new Item instance within the admin page, hide_item is set to True by default as expected...

**Right now I think my best solution might be to make another model that holds hide/display information for all items and keep it separate from the item models.**

Wondering if anyone might now how to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most elegant way to do it, but I ended up making a separate model that stores show/hide information and syncs with the item to be displayed.

I did this using a BooleanField for the show/hide and a readonly OneToOne(Item) field to sync with the item I want to display.

Worked well.